# Is there a way to adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle without invoking multiple database calls in this code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I have a portion of code that basically retrieving a Bean object from the database through Hibernate, making some changes to the values of two or three properties before storing it back into the database.

Let's look at a real example. My application's purpose is to allow a couple of people to take a MCQ test. To prevent overloading the database by updating the score every time the user submits an answer, I am storing the score counter in a `HashMap` which will be flushed to the database at the end of the test. I also require a timestamp to be updated indicating the time that the test has been concluded.

My current design involves two functions.

This first function flushes the score from the `HashMap` to the database.

```
private void flushScoreToDatabase(String id) {

    int score = scoreMap.get(id);

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Student student = (Student)session.get(Student.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
        student.setScore(score);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        scoreMap.remove(id);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

The second function will involve updating the timestamp.

```
private void updateTimestamp(String id) {
    Session session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    try {
        sesssion.beginTransaction();
        Student student = (Student)session.get(Student.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
        student.setEndTime(timestamp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

Both functions will be wrapped by another function that gets the `id` of the user from the authenticated session.

This is pretty expensive because this involves two `SELECT` statements as well as two `UPDATE` statements just to update two different properties for the same user.

Is there a neater way to design the code while adhering to the SRP?

Comment: How is it related to SRP? you need to rethink what your question is.

Comment: I think you have a overly-micro concept of the Single Responsibility Principle.  "This class is responsible for synchronizing in-memory state with the database" is a perfectly fine level to define a responsibility at.  "A method is only allowed to update one field at a time" is just silliness.

Comment: @Affe So it is alright in your opinion for both updates to be done in the same function? What if instead of just two simple updates it's four or five updates to different fields that each required multiple lines of code to derive the updated value? I used to do this in the past and it seemed quite messy when I went back and read the code.

Comment: Look into using an IOC container and declarative transaction management?  That will make it easy for the hibernate session to span multiple method calls.  (Also, reality, "good OO design" and high performance interactions with relational databases are sort of natural enemies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally SRP is discussed with reference to a class or module, but I think you're right to consider the meanings of functions, a "ragbag" function whose jobs is to "x and y and z" may not be good design.

Also performing two separate transactions to update score and timestamp is surely excessive.

I would tend to consider the functions in terms of a business meaning, say:

```
snapshotTest()
```

and

```
endTest()
```

and have a utility function that updates the student's score used by both of those.

In passing, all that transactional stuff is getting in the way of your business logic, can you not use EJBs or Spring to push that to a container?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do agree that having two separate transactions to update the score and timestamp is excessive. I guess I should rethink the design according to what you suggest.

Comment: I also agree that the transactional stuff is quite messy. This is my first Java application so I had not discovered Spring and the like when I first started. I would like to keep things consistent in the same app though so I'm still sticking with this way for now. I'll definitely be using Spring or similar if I start with a new Java app.

Comment: Adding to what djna said, it looks like the design in the question is data centric rather than logic centric. I my experience object-oriented design is a good match for logic centric applications, but it's not very good for data oriented applications. The reason being the data centric application require a more structured approach (e.g. the *transaction script* pattern).